# Indoor navigation Access Points or WDS (WiFi Repeater)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I want to attempt a small in-door WiFi navigation project I have no problems regarding programming but I'm lost on the Networking part.

Basically what I need is WiFi routers under same network name basically one is the host to which internet is connected and is broadcasting WiFi which shows to all devices as network name (SSID) NavigationNetwork others just server to extend the range of the said network.

I'm a little bit confused about how AP & WDS works. Basically my app will work by connecting to the NavigationNetwork and then scan for all the AP/Routers each will return it's MAC address & Signal Strength.

But this won't work if one AP is broadcasting NavigationNetwork1 and host is broadcasting NavigationNetwork2.

In addition when it comes to WDS can you still get that information from each router or does it show up as one single router ?